# How to make docker make request on service name instead of IP Address

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, docker-network

I am trying to create a fabric Multi-org multi-VM using overlay network.  Hyperledger fabric validates the peers(containers) using their service names. Now, the problem here is the peers are providing their IP address not service names in communication causing a failure in TLS validation. Is there a way to make containers make grpcs calls only using service names and not IP address.

Answer (score 0):

In a production scenario you would use DNS servers to map the addresses from host names, and there would be no IP addresses in any of your configuration files.  I would encourage you to try and adopt the same approach in a development/test environment the /etc/hosts file is the obvious answer for the VMs themselves to resolve hostnames, and there is a feature in docker-compose for adding extra hosts to the /etc/hosts file in the containers e.g. the following line goes in a docker-compose yaml file:

```
    extra_hosts:
  - "peer0.omac.cons.com:192.168.153.157"
```

Comment: Hello R Thatcher, Thanks for the response. I do agree with you that dns mapping will be performed for production. But I am working on POC and as suggested I added configuration in /etc/hosts as well. But, it didn't work for me.